# Retrieve certain amount of children from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a **tableView** that loads only a certain amount of values, let's say like 30 or so from my database.

I've looked at other tutorials for this, but they are in **Objective-C** or some other language. **Swift** would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Reference to the FireBase Documentation see:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

There is Objective-C and Swift Code referenced.

In short: you can make use of two functions:

```
open func queryLimitedToLast(limit: UInt) -> FIRDatabaseQuery
open func queryLimitedToFirst(limit: UInt) -> FIRDatabaseQuery
```

UInt is a data type "unsigned int". Means: pass a positive number to the function :-)

Don't forget, to observe the results of the query by calling the "observeEventType" on it - this function contains a block, in which you can make use of your items (e.g. you could add them to an array of items. The array could be used for your tableview's datasource. Finally, reload the tableview

An Example to call it, could look like this (for your 30 entries) (e.g. in your viewDidLoad):

DataSource Array Declaration as Class Variable

```
var objects = [MyObjects]()
```

Perform your Query:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = Firebase(url:"https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs")
    ref.queryLimitedToLast(30)
       .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        println(snapshot.key)
        var newItems: [MyObject] = []
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let myObject = MyObject(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(myObject)
        }
        self.objects = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

And the interesting table view DataSource method could look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }
```

Comment: Some minor bugs: you declared `var objects` twice; you forgot the `self` prefix when setting `objects` inside the query.

Comment: Thank you, I had extended the first approach with the class variable, thus the duplicate declaration. Answer will be updated :)

Comment: How would I append to the last 30? So I want to initially fill my table with the last 30, but when something new comes in I just want to append without losing any of that 30.

Comment: @LukeIrvin please post a new question with this specific request, as it might also help others seeing the specific solution strategy.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift**. Get a `FIRDatabaseReference` to the parent node and then run a query using this function:

```
func queryLimited(toFirst limit: UInt) -> FIRDatabaseQuery
```

And then retrieve the resulting children using:

```
func observeSingleEvent(of eventType: FIRDataEventType, with block: @escaping (FIRDataSnapshot) -> Void)
```